# Update an Entry into mysql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in coding and i was recently chosen to start training in C# and Asp.Net. I am trying to update an entry into the database but to no avail. The delete, create and read functions work properly. (i know that my code lacks try and catch)

I 've tried different solutions that i found while googling but since i am still training i never fully understand if what i am following is completely correct.
Currently i am able to diplay the fields with their info when navigating to the "Article" i am trying to edit but when i click the Save button nothing happens.

This is in my Article Context file:

```
public Article EditSingleArticle(int id, int userID, string Title, string Body)
    {
        Article article = new Article();
        using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdslct = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Article WHERE ID=@id", conn);
            MySqlCommand cmdul = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Article SET userID=@userID,Title=@Title,Body=@Body WHERE ID=@id", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmdslct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            cmdslct.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", article.userID);
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", article.Title);
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", article.Body);
            cmdul.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmdslct.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    article = new Article()
                    {
                        userID = reader.GetInt32("userID"),
                        ID = reader.GetInt32("ID"),
                        Title = reader.GetString("Title"),
                        Body = reader.GetString("Body")
                    };
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

The code below is in my ArticleController file:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id, int userID, string Title, string Body)
    {
        ArticleContext context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ArticleContext)) as ArticleContext;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(context.EditSingleArticle(id, userID, Title, Body));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I don't get any error messages but the article i am trying to edit never updates

Comment: You are not adding your id parameter to your update command, so there will be no matching entries in your database to update (`WHERE ID=@id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update query you are using a where condition which uses parameter @id. But you are not passing the ID argument to your query. Add a argument '@id' for the update query. 
Add this line to the code

```
cmul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Comment: UPDATE Article SET userID=@userID,Title=@Title,Body=@Body WHERE ID=@id are you refering to this query? if yes what should i change

Comment: Yes in the update query you are using this condition 'WHERE ID=@id'. But @id is not passed as argument to query. To the parameter list add cmul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

Comment: i have tried that but i still dont get the result i want

Comment: Then check if the correct id is getting passed in the argument

Comment: when i use the select query, when i navigate to the edit page all the fields are already populated with the details that were passed when the article was created. on the update article query though i cannot get it to save the changes

Comment: thank you for the help you actually helped me with your answer to find the solution. I've changed my update query to "UPDATE Article SET userID='" + userID + "',Title='" + Title + "', Body ='" + Body + "' WHERE ID ='" + id + "'" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that article object only have the default empty fields because you are calling  cmdslct.[ExecuteNonQuery()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) that does not return data at all, only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete.

So you should call [ExecuteReader()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteReader.htm) that returns an object that can iterate over the entire result set while only keeping one record in memory at a time.

Your code should looks like the following code in order to work as expected:

```
        Article article = new Article();
        using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdslct = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Article WHERE ID=@id", conn);
            MySqlCommand cmdul = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Article SET userID=@userID,Title=@Title,Body=@Body WHERE ID=@id", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmdslct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmdslct.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    article = new Article()
                    {
                        userID = reader.GetInt32("userID"),
                        ID = reader.GetInt32("ID"),
                        Title = reader.GetString("Title"),
                        Body = reader.GetString("Body")
                    };
                }
            }
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", article.userID);
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", article.Title);
            cmdul.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", article.Body);
            cmdul.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Regards,

Comment: i have copied your code but unless i copied something wrong i don't get the result i want